# How use left join and/or Right Join and/or Inner Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I've use JOIN in this query, i don't know how but i used direct reference and the result is corret... Pls Help me

Thanks

Question: 
What's proprieties name where license plate (placa) = LVU9132

```
 SELECT P.NOME
FROM MODELO M
    ,VEICULO V
    ,PROPRIETARIO P
WHERE P.COD_PROP = V.PROPRIETARIO
    AND V.MODELO = M.COD_MOD
    AND V.PLACA = 'LVU9132';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query in the new syntax:

```
SELECT P.NOME
FROM MODELO M 
inner join VEICULO V on V.MODELO = M.COD_MOD
inner join PROPRIETARIO P on P.COD_PROP = V.PROPRIETARIO
WHERE V.PLACA = 'LVU9132';
```

An inner join requires both matching rows to be present. If the matching `PROPRIETARIO` row is not found, the `VEICULO` row won't display either.

Use the following if you want to see the vehicle row even if it has no matching proprietor.
The left join return nulls for right hand table `PROPRIETARIO` if no matching rows found. Note that left join requires the left hand table to be present but doesn't care if there are no matching rows on right hand table.

```
SELECT P.NOME
FROM MODELO M,VEICULO V,PROPRIETARIO P
WHERE V.PROPRIETARIO *= P.COD_PROP      -- left outer join
    AND V.MODELO = M.COD_MOD
    AND V.PLACA = 'LVU9132';
```

New syntax (ANSI92 standard)

```
SELECT P.NOME
FROM MODELO M 
inner join VEICULO V on V.MODELO = M.COD_MOD
left join PROPRIETARIO P on P.COD_PROP = V.PROPRIETARIO
WHERE V.PLACA = 'LVU9132';
```

The old-style syntax is no longer supported in SQL Server 2012, because it can return incorrect results.

Comment: Thanks John D, i'm never used JOIN, i know only this way P.COD_PROP = V.PROPRIETARIO. But your explanation has been perfect!! Thanks!!

Comment: `INNER JOIN` is the same as `JOIN` -- I think it is clear not to have the extra word.

Comment: @Vitor You're welcome. FYI: Either of these conditions work the same way:
`V.PROPRIETARIO *= P.COD_PROP` or `P.COD_PROP =* V.PROPRIETARIO`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an outer join to answer the question (as posed);

```
SELECT P.NOME
FROM MODELO M JOIN
     VEICULO V
     ON V.MODELO = M.COD_MOD JOIN
     PROPRIETARIO P
     ON P.COD_PROP = V.PROPRIETARIO
WHERE V.PLACA = 'LVU9132';
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff!!! It's as posed, but my teacher wanna only this way (left join and etc...)! I'm so angry!!!